# Windows .bat file starting java command : how to find it in process list

Tags: java, node.js, windows

I have a `.bat` file composed of a single java command : `java -jar someProgram.jar`.

This `.bat` file is executed by a nodejs process, using the `os.exec` command. Before executing the script, I want to check if it has already been executed, so I'm listing the processes list and I search for "someProgram.jar", but I can't find it, because it seems to appear under a single `'java'` name.

Is there a way to get processes list with more informations (like the full command), or any other solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Launch your Java program with a dummy, but recognizable command-line switch like `-Dfoo=bar`. Then, rather than search for `java` in the process list, search for `foo=bar` (or whatever).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Implementing a single-instance program is a solved issue.